# jinja2 for loop in inventory file

Tags: loops, ansible, jinja2, inventory

I'm searching a way to do a loop inside of an inventory file (I don't even know if it's possible...?)
I explain myself:
I have one var file in group_vars/All containing a list with ip address like:

```
doca_dns_server:
- x.x.x.1
- x.x.x.2
```

In a second inventory file, stored in host_vars section I want to loop on this variable for build some firewall rules.
I tried this:

```
226 output ntp udp accepted:
  {% for srv in ip_address%}    
  - udp dport ntp ip daddr {{ srv }} ct state new accept
  {% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work, I hope it's a syntax issue but I don't find any example.

```
PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found character that cannot start any token

The error appears to be in '/home/mpileyre/ansible/inventories/hds/pprod/host_vars/tibrin2-ppd/firewall.yml': line 68, column 2, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  225 output dns tcp udp accepted:
{% for ip in doca_dns_servers %}
 ^ here
```

As I could use some jinja2 function (like replace) in my var files, I was wondering if I could do a loop :) but maybe i'm wrong...

Expected result is:

```
226 output ntp udp accepted:    
  - udp dport ntp ip daddr x.x.x.1 ct state new accept
  - udp dport ntp ip daddr x.x.x.2 ct state new accept
```

Comment: `But this doesn't work` => [can you please define this point as precisely as possible?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Moreover, can you give a complete example of your inventory files (because your extract does not look as an inventory at all). And since your are new here: please do not answer in comments: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70624345/edit) your question. You should as well read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create an MCVE](/help/mcve)

Comment: Meanwhile as a pure guess and without any warranty.... => `226 output ntp udp accepted: "{{ ip_address | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'udp dport ntp ip daddr \\g<1> ct state new accept') | list }}"`

Comment: I just edit. Sorry for the lack of explanation, I admit, it was not clear...
I just try your suggestion and it's work like a charm ! very thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to understand Ansible a little bit more.

An inventory file is a "state" or "description of the environment". The tasks that you want to do are port of "playbooks" or "roles".

As already mentioned in the comments to your question, I guess, the "second inventory" is not an inventory, but a task. You want to do somethng with the ip addresses from within the inventory (the definition).

If you need to define some firewall rules for all your IPs, you define in the inventory the IPs and the rules (or the informations about rule specification. Then you use the playbooks (or just one task, to iterate over this informations.

Your inventory cannot be dynamic in this scenario (Jinja foreach isn't working, I think) and also it isn't necessary here.

So acording to your given inventory define a task in a playbook

```
- name: "Create rules"
  shell: "....your command here together with {{ source }} containing one ip..."
  loop: "{{ ip_address }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: source
```

Comment: Suggestion made by Zeitounator has worked, but thnaks for your answer.